# how to compare values from a list in Linq to Entity (any / contains)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

There is a list, `policiesToDelete` of entity class, `MonitoringRelations`. Out of this list I have selected two elements and construed a new list:

```
var policyKeysToDelete = policiesToDelete
    .Select(r => new {r.PolicyId, r.GroupId})
    .ToList();
```

Now, I have a query where I want to compare elements from `policyKeysToDelete` list.

```
var objectsToDelete = (from p in storageContext.MonitoringRelations
                       where policyKeysToDelete
                            .Any(x => x == new {p.PolicyId, p.GroupId})
                       select p)
                       .ToList();
```

**The problem**: the query above throws this exception:

`NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

I have tried changing the anonymous list to a `list<tuple<PolicyId, GroupId>>` , but that also didn't help, throwing the almost same exception. I tried using `Contains` in place of `Any` but that also didn't help.

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect the problem in anonymous list (policyKeysToDelete), can anything be done with that so that it is no more anonymous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF cannot translate a list of complex objects into the SQL query. What EF *can* do, is translate a list of simple values into SQL when you use it with the `.Contains` method.

So if you extract a list of PolicyId's and a list of GroupId's from the `policyKeysToDelete`, and use it to select as much as you can with EF, then you can do the full check in the resultset which is then in-memory, using Linq-to-objects.

**Warning**: you *are* extracting too much from the database, so depending on the amount of data, a different solution might be better.

```
var policyKeysToDelete = policiesToDelete
    .Select(r => new {r.PolicyId, r.GroupId})
    .ToList();

// List of values types, which can be translated to SQL
var policyIds = policyKeysToDelete.Select(x => x.PolicyId).ToList();
var groupIds = policyKeysToDelete.Select(x => x.GroupId).ToList();

var objectsToDelete = storageContext.MonitoringRelations

    // Do the part that we can do in the database, which is select the records
    // which have an corresponding PolicyId or GroupId
    .Where(x => policyIds.Contains(x.PolicyId) || groupIds.Contains(x.GroupId))

    // Use this method to indicate that whatever follows after should not be
    // translated to SQL
    .AsEnumerable()

    // Do the full check in-memory
    .Where(x => policyKeysToDelete
        .Any(y => x.PolicyId == y.PolicyId && x.GroupId == y.GroupId)
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! this was a good orientation. I did a little modification to your solution and it worked fine.

Comment: why did you say that too much is being extracted from the db? When the condition is already placed for `policyId` or `groupId` while making the db query, I imagine only a very small number of record(s).

Comment: @dev_wired Because the query above checks for either PolicyId or GroupId, but not the combination of them. This is something you cannot do since you cannot translate the combination of the two values into SQL. Therefore, this must be checked on the .NET side, in-memory.

Comment: @dev_wired Suppose you have 2 combinations for [PolicyId, GroupId], namely [2, A] and [3, B]. The db query retrieves records which have `PolicyId IN (2, 3) OR GroupId IN (A, B)`. But not the combination, and therefore, it is (very) possible that you will retrieve too much data.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the warning, but even with OR condition I don't suspect too much data in my case.